# What are the primary determining factors for the latency of an Internet hop?

Tags: networking, internet, routing

Consider the following output from `traceroute`, from me in Sweden to a server in the US:

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)                                   0.127 ms    0.148 ms    0.167 ms
 2  gw-n1-rny-a13.ias.bredband.telia.com (2.248.176.129)        2.404 ms    2.414 ms    2.424 ms
 3  s-b6-link.telia.net (62.115.139.49)                         1.391 ms    1.401 ms    1.607 ms
 4  s-akix-i1-link.telia.net (213.155.134.9)                    1.610 ms    1.605 ms    1.590 ms
 5  as5580-ic-155269-s-akix-i1.c.telia.net (80.239.161.18)      5.091 ms    1.572 ms    1.582 ms
 6  eth2-4.edge1.sto1.se.as5580.net (78.152.34.214)            10.783 ms   10.126 ms   10.085 ms
 7  eth15-2.r1.fra1.de.as5580.net (78.152.34.217)              21.254 ms   20.934 ms   20.921 ms
 8  eth13-1.core1.par2.fr.as5580.net (78.152.44.244)           29.821 ms   29.912 ms   29.924 ms
 9  eth7-1.core1.lon2.uk.as5580.net (78.152.44.242)            34.987 ms   34.986 ms   34.971 ms
10  eth1-2.edge1.nyc4.us.as5580.net (80.94.64.134)            114.090 ms  122.484 ms  122.485 ms
11  78.152.57.87 (78.152.57.87)                               123.962 ms  123.924 ms  123.934 ms
12  10ge-1-2-0.01-02.er1.buf1.colocrossing.com (23.94.31.14)  124.270 ms  124.094 ms  124.247 ms
13  core.servermania.com (172.245.211.134)                    124.732 ms  124.733 ms  124.814 ms
```

(I cleaned it up slightly to make the numbers line up, but that shouldn't matter. I'm interested in principles rather than this particular data anyway.)

I'm curious what factors determine the latency each of these hops add. The most obvious one would be physical distance, but it's obvious that that is not the primary factor, since the 125 ms of the entire request would (almost) be enough for a full revolution around the Earth, which is clearly several factors longer than this request travels physically. I cannot see that the actual bandwidth of the links would have much of an impact (on anything but packet loss, in case they are overloaded, that is).

What are the factors that add latency apart from physical distance? Is it some sort of internal buffering and/or processing in the various routers, and, in that case, of what kind (would looking through routing tables take multiple tens of milliseconds?), or is it some hidden retransmission on underlying protocol levels, or what?

Not having dealt with "big iron" routers of the kind I suspect are being used in these cases, I'm curious what kind of factors determine their performance in terms of latency.

Comment: Router processing adds to latency. The router has to examine the destination address, then consult the routing table to determine the net hop, and that takes time. If a link is congested, the packet may wait in queue for a while before the router is able to forward the packet. Satellite links can add quite a bit of latency, because the signal must travel over 44K miles round trip (that's about a quarter second of light travel time).

Answer (score 3):

**What factors determine the latency?**

Network Latency can be caused by:

- Serialization Delay - caused by having to transmit data through routers/switches in packet sized chunks.
- Queuing Delay - time spent in a router's queues waiting for transmission. This is mostly related to line contention (full interfaces), since without
  congestion there is very little need for a measurable queue.
- Propagation Delay - time spent in transit, in which the signal is traveling over the transmission medium. This is primarily a limitation based on the
  speed of light, or other electromagnetic propagation.

See [What is Network Latency and Why Does It Matter?](http://www.o3bnetworks.com/media/40980/white%20paper_latency%20matters.pdf) for more information.